# All 10.10 apps will work after going to 11.04?

Tags: upgrade

As many of you, i use my ubuntu machine for work, in my case, development. As i am very anxious to go 11.04 as soon as it goes live, will my previous 10.10 applications work on 11.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every application of yours that worked in 10.10 should work perfectly fine with 11.04 as well, as even GNOME 3 (which is dramatically different from GNOME 2.x both in looks and under-the-hood) has strong backward compatibility with classic GNOME apps. The problem might occur in vice-versa case, when you develop an app that targets particularly the Unity or new features of GNOME 3.

Answer (score 0):

In my case every application just worked. In the worst scenario you still have Gnome2 (instead of the default Unity), so I guess you will experience no problem running your applications.